# How to give onPressed action to BottomNavigationBar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a BottomNavigationBar in flutter,and i want to on click of the individual widgets of the BottomNavigationBar, so on press button "Add Contact" it should navigate me to the next page which is my FifthScreen.

````
Widget _myListView(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(children: [
    Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
          children: ListTile.divideTiles(
            context: context,
            tiles: [
              ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('Icons.account_circle'),
                ),
                title: Text('User 1'),
                subtitle: Text('Hello'),
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FourthScreen())),
              ),
            ],
          ).toList(),
        )),
    BottomNavigationBar(items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add), label: "Add Contact",),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.group), label: "Contacts"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: "Settings"),
    ])
  ]);
}```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**BottomNavigationBar** has an onTap method that returns an **int** (the current selected index of the navBar)

```
 BottomNavigationBar(
      onTap: (value) {
        if (value == 0) Navigator.of(context).push(...);
        if (value == 1) Navigator.of(context).push(...);
        if (value == 2) Navigator.of(context).push(...);
      },
    ),
```

Of course, index 0 in your case is "Add contact", index 1 is "Contacts" and so on...

Answer (score 1):

The `onTap:` implementation is correct. But also do not forget to specify the `currentIndex` field of the currently selected item, so that this changes the state of the bottom navigation menu, if required of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onTap() method of the BottomNavigationBar. More details [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)